# Prove that if Z lies on the unit circle then z-1/z is an imaginary number

Tags: linear-algebra

**Given a complex number :** **z=x+iy**, **y is not equal to 0**, **x is not equal to 0.**
prove if Z lies on the unit circle then $z-\frac1z$ is an imaginary number.
I tried using $a^2 + b^2 = R^2$, but did not understand how to start.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $Z$ is an imaginary number iff $\bar Z=-Z.$ And $|z|=1$ iff $\bar z=1/z.$

Comment: Why not try substituting $x+iy$ in for $z$ in the expression $z-\frac1z$, and putting everything into standard form ($a+bi$) and see what happens?

Comment: I would add that $\frac1z=\frac{\overline{z}}{\vert z \vert ^2}$ is useful since we know the denominator is real and $\vert z \vert = \vert \overline{z} \vert $.