# Prove associativity of the binary operation $(a,b)*(c,d) =\begin{cases}(a+c-b,d)&\text{if }c>b\\(a,b-c+d)&\text{else}\end{cases}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to prove the associativity of the binary operation $*$ on $ℕ ∪\{0\}$ defined by
$$(a,b)*(c,d) =\begin{cases}(a+c-b,d)&\text{if }c>b\\(a,b-c+d)&\text{else}\end{cases}$$

I proved the first two cases:

1. If $c > b$ and $e > d,$ then:

   - $(a,b)*((c,d)*(e,f)) = (a,b)*(c+e-d,f) = (a+c+e-d-b,f),$
   - $((a,b)*(c,d))*(e,f) = (a+c-b,d)*(e,f) = (a+c-b+e-d,f).$
2. If $c > b$ and $e\le d,$ then:

   - $(a,b)*((c,d)*(e,f)) = (a,b)*(c,d-e+f) = (a+c-b,d-e+f)$
   - $((a,b)*(c,d))*(e,f) = (a+c-b,d)*(e,f) = (a+c-b,d-e+f).$

For Case 3:

- If $c\le b$ and $e > d,$ then:

  - $(a,b)((c,d)(e,f)) = (a,b)*(c+e-d,f) =?$
  - $((a,b)(c,d))(e,f) = (a,b-c+d)*(e,f) =?$

Here is where i got stuck. Any help showing how I can continue from here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please use mathjax. [Here is the quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742).

Comment: [You have been told about MathJax before.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577165/prove-that-if-z-lies-on-the-unit-circle-then-z-1-z-is-an-imaginary-number#comment9633905_4577165)

Comment: I wonder why question and answer were downvoted. Is it only because of the lack of formatting of the question? Imo the OP showed sufficient research effort so it shouldn't be  treated as a "poor quality post".

Comment: I disagree with you about the downvote on the question, I agree it is not necessarily a poor quality post, though, and I agree with you about the downvote on the current answer; hence my upvote, @AnneBauval.

Comment: I honestly wonder how this post could be declared "needing details or clarity". It was absolutely clear and well detailed.  Since the only problem seemed to be the formatting, I just improved it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a neat proof of this by using another description of [this monoid](https:///en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicyclic_semigroup), namely it has the presentation $\langle p,q\mid pq=1 \rangle$. As a result of this, any word can be reduced to the form $q^ap^b$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ and we have

$$(q^ap^b)(q^cp^d)=q^ep^f$$
where
$$(e,f)=(a,b)*(c,d).$$

Answer (score 0):

$(a,b)*((c,d)*(e,f))$ and $((a,b)*(c,d))*(e,f)$ are both equal to:

- $(a-b+c-d+e,f)$ if $e\ge d$ and $e-d\ge b-c$, or equivalently if
  ($c\ge b$ and $e\ge d$) or ($c\le b$ and $e-d\ge b-c$),
- $(a,b-c+d-e+f)$ if $c\le b$ and $e-d\le b-c$, or equivalently if
  ($e\le d$ and $c\le b$) or ($e\ge d$ and $e-d\le b-c$),
- $(a-b+c,d-e+f)$ else, i.e. if $e\le d$ and $b\le c.$